orange3 addon there's an issue with the internet connection
I tried to use the add-on
But it came out like this
there's an issue with the internet connection.
please check you are connected to the internet.
if you are behind a proxy. please set it in preferences-network

The internet is connected and no proxy is used.
and this is detail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 198, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 779, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1048, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 616, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 213, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000240FCBFDF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000240FCBFDF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='orange.biolab.si', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /addons/list (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000240FCBFDF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\orangecanvas\application\utils\addons.py", line 350, in list_available_versions
    defaults = config.addon_defaults_list()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\config.py", line 166, in addon_defaults_list
    return session.get(OFFICIAL_ADDON_LIST).json()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Orange\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 694, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='orange.biolab.si', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /addons/list (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000240FCBFDF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다')))


Even if I turned off the firewall just in case, it stayed the same.
